# how to interpret Principal component Analysis result for feature selection

Tags: pca, dimensionality-reduction

I am implementing PCA on unsupervised data. I chose 10 components and the data features are almost 400. Generated two tables one is telling variance of every principal component. The other is telling the correlation between every component and feature. How to interpret these values and select features. I have to look at variance or look at the correlation table.

In table 2 Principal component 1 has a high correlation with F1, F2, F4, F5, F7, F8 by looking at this which one to drop and pick. Can anyone help me in interpreting this? and help me in choosing the best feature by looking at the PCA result.

And the last thing will be is it goood to choose 10 PC for 400 features data

The black figure generated through this code
pca_df = pd.concat(pca_list, axis=1).T.set_index('n')
print(pca_df)

the second table shown in figure used this code

```
features_df = (pd.concat(feature_weight_list)
                    .pivot(index='n', columns='features', values='values'))
print(features_df)

# sns.set_palette(palette)
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import os
import warnings
warnings.simplefilter(action='ignore', category=FutureWarning)
import numpy as np # linear algebra
import pandas as pd # data processing, CSV file I/O (e.g. pd.read_csv)
#os.chdir('data')
# from colorsetup import colors, palette
# sns.set_palette(palette)
#%matplotlib inline

data = pd.read_csv('C:/Users/user122/Downloads//mydata.csv')
print(data.shape)
##DROP ALL CPUMNS WITH NaN
data= df.dropna(axis=1, how="any")
columns_names=data.columns.tolist()
print("Columns names:")
print(columns_names)
print(data.shape)
data.head()
# fill all null wioth zero data.fillna(0)
#data=data.drop(\['Name', 'QQ', 'Times'\],  axis=1) 
print(data.dtypes)


#convert to floats
for col in data.columns:
    data\[col\]= data\[col\].astype(np.float)
#preserve orignal data
data_orig = data.copy()
#o we're going to examine the correlation between each one of our different features. 
# And recall this will be important as when we are doing PCA. What we will be looking 
# for is if two features are very highly correlated, they're not adding any extra information 
# and we want to remove or reduce those or combine a few to end up with less features overall. So if they're highly correlated, we can probably remove some without losing much variance from the overall data set. We're then going to perform any transformations and scale our data using whatever scaling method you prefer.
corr_mat = data.corr()
for x in range(corr_mat.shape\[0\]):
    corr_mat.iloc\[x,x\] = 0.0
print(corr_mat)
corr_mat.abs().idxmax()
#examine the skew values and log transform
log_columns = data.skew().sort_values(ascending= False)
log_columns = log_columns.loc\[log_columns > 0.75\]
log_columns
#log transformation
for col in log_columns.index:
    data\[col\]= np.log1p(data\[col\])
#scale data again by using min max scalar just to mix things u
#from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
mms = MinMaxScaler()
for col in data.columns:
    data\[col\]= mms.fit_transform(data\[\[col\]\])
#isualize relation between 2 var
sns.set_context('notebook')
sns.set_style('white')
sns.pairplot(data);

from sklearn.preprocessing import FunctionTransformer
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
log_transformer =FunctionTransformer(np.log1p)
estimators = \[('log1p', log_transformer), ('minmaxscale', MinMaxScaler())\]
pipeline = Pipeline(estimators)
#convert the orignal data
data_pipe = pipeline.fit_transform(data_orig)
np.allclose(data_pipe,data)
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
pca_list = list()
feature_weight_list = list()
#fit a range of PCA models
for n in range(1,6):
    #create fit the model
    PCAmod = PCA(n_components=n)
    PCAmod.fit(data)
    #X_test.fillna(X_test.mean())
    #store the model and variance
    pca_list.append(pd.Series({ 'n': n,
                                'model': PCAmod,
                                'var': PCAmod.explained_variance_ratio_.sum()}))
    #claculate and store feature importance
    weights = PCAmod.explained_variance_ratio_.reshape(-1,1)/PCAmod.explained_variance_ratio_.sum()
    overall_contribution = np.abs(PCAmod.components_)*weights
    abs_feature_values = overall_contribution.sum(axis=0)
    feature_weight_list.append(pd.DataFrame({ 'n': n,
                                              'features': data.columns,
                                              'values': abs_feature_values/abs_feature_values.sum()}))
pca_df = pd.concat(pca_list, axis=1).T.set_index('n')
print(pca_df)
#create a table of feature importance for each data column
feature_weight_list\[1\]
features_df = (pd.concat(feature_weight_list)
                .pivot(index='n', columns='features', values='values'))
print(features_df)
sns.set_context('talk')
ax = pca_df\['var'\].plot(kind='bar')
ax.set(xlabel='no of dimesions',
       ylabel='percent explained variance',
       title='explained variance vs dimesions');
#plot for feature importance
ax=features_df.plot(kind='bar')
ax.legend(loc='upper right')
ax.set(xlabel='no of dimesnions',
       ylabel= 'relative importance',
       title='feature importance vs dimesions');
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Do you want to select features in the original feature space, or a limited number of principal components for downstream analysis? The top PCs will capture variance better than any of the individual features (by definition), but you'll likely need to measure many features to calculate any PC score. If you just want to build a model with fewer dimensions, PCs might be the way to go, but if you want to build a model where you don't need to measure all 400 features, you'll likely need to select in the original feature space.

Comment: I need to select good feature using PCA for my model . what i need to do? and how to interpret these results